# how to skip formation of single quotes for the variable during prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, database, connection, prepared-statement, session-variables

Im using prepared statement for setting a session variable using following code in prepared statement.

> ```
> String sessionVariable = "optimizer_search_depth"
> String sessionValue = "10";
> preparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("set session ? = ?");
> stmt.setString(1, sessionVariable);
> stmt.setString(2, sessionValue);
> stmt.executeQuery();
> ```

if i use this im getting SQL string as below:

```
> set session 'optimizer_search_depth' = '10';
```

this will give an sql Exception, since there is a single quote around them. I need to form a query without single quotes like

```
> set session optimizer_search_depth = 10;
```

Comment: use string concatenation for the option

Comment: i can't understand. Can you kindly explain me?

Comment: Mabye `stmt.setInt(2, sessionValue);`

Comment: how to avoid single quotes around optimizer_search_depth?

Comment: you cannot parameterize variable names. Why do you want to send it as a variable?

Comment: since im getting variable externally, im parameterizing it as i have sql injection problem @YourCommonSense

Comment: Why you are getting the variable **name** externally?

Comment: my application demands it. I ll get list of session variables from an xml file and set it. @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 0):

You need some dynamic SQL here. The code should work as:

```
String sessionVariable = "optimizer_search_depth"
String sessionValue = "10";
preparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
  "set session '" + sessionVariable + "' = ?"
  );
stmt.setString(1, sessionValue);
stmt.executeQuery();
```

Make sure the `sessionVariable` is very controlled and it's not a free value that is coming from an external source such as a web interface or other. Otherwise, this code will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Im getting multiple variable names externally and adding them to a list..And i will take each variable from the list and execute in above query. If i concatenate, there is a problem of SQL injection

Comment: Yes, that's a SQL Injection vulnerability. Did you previously provide the selection list to the external source? If so, you could return the "index" of the selected item in the list; then you can rebuild the value internally using the index and the list. This way the value is always coming from an internal source.

Comment: Check the value you are receving from outside is a valid one from a well-known list. Not something like "DELETE DATABASE". If the value is on the well-known list it's OK; otherwise, reject it.